# how to login user throught rest api in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

hey i just creat a rest api in wordpress for login its work on old user but when i creat a new user its show invalid user name 400 error
    my code is  its work on old user but error in new user like this
{"code":400,"msg":"Invalid username"}
and in register api how to convert user password to wordpress hash password

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_api_hooks' );
function register_api_hooks() {
  register_rest_route(
    'custom-plugin', '/login/',
    array(
      'methods'  => 'GET',
      'callback' => 'login',
    )
  );
}
function login($request){
    $creds = array();
      $creds['user_login'] = $request["username"];
      $creds['user_password'] = md5($request["password"]);
     $creds['remember'] = true;
      $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
    {
       $user->get_error_message();
       return $myArray = ['code'=>400, 'msg'=>'Invalid username'];
    }
    else
    {
    $token = wp_get_session_token();
  return $myArray = ['code'=>200, 'msg'=>'Success', 'user'=> $user ,'token'=>  $token];
}
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What's the reason for throwing error 400? If you already have access to that error message, why don't you check it?

Comment: i check it and solve the login problem but i don't know how to use post in user registration in rest api .iam new in wordpress pls if you know so reply

Comment: What do you mean by "how to use post in user registration in rest api"? Can you reduce the code to the relevant parts, and post which kind of request you are using including sample input data?

Comment: HERE IS MY CODE FOR REGISTER USER THROUGHT POST
add_action('rest_api_init', 'wp_rest_user_endpoints');
function wp_rest_user_endpoints($request) {
  register_rest_route('wp/v2', 'users/register', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'wc_rest_user_endpoint_handler',
  ));
}
function wc_rest_user_endpoint_handler($request = null) {
  $response = array();
  $parameters = $request->get_json_params();
  $username = sanitize_text_field($parameters['username']);
  $password= sanitize_text_field($parameters['password']);
but when i echo $email or $user name No Data show

Comment: but when i echo no data found..and error show that route not found